# Why UITextView/UITextField can't implement the UITextInput on iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

Apple supply an example to implement the UITextInput based on a UIView. I tried to do the same thing based on the UITextView/UITextField but failed. That's why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses a private class as delegate for UITextInput on these classes. That means you cannot hook your own code in there because you cannot subclass a private class.